# react-firebaseui StyledFirebaseAuth is not getting compiled

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebaseui

I am using react-firebaseui for authentication, according to the documentation i have written the code

```
import React from "react";
import StyledFirebaseAuth from "react-firebaseui/StyledFirebaseAuth";
import firebase from "firebase";

const firebaseConfig = {
  ...
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);


// Configure FirebaseUI.
const uiConfig = {
  // Popup signin flow rather than redirect flow.
  signInFlow: "popup",
  // Redirect to /signedIn after sign in is successful. Alternatively you can provide a callbacks.signInSuccess function.
  //   signInSuccessUrl: '/signedIn',
  // We will display Google and Facebook as auth providers.
  signInOptions: [firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID],
};

export const SignInWith = () => (
<>
    <p>Login</p>
    <StyledFirebaseAuth uiConfig={uiConfig} firebaseAuth={firebase.auth()} />
</>
);
```

but i keep getting this error

> ./node_modules/firebaseui/dist/esm.js
> Attempted import error: 'app' is not exported from 'firebase/app' (imported as 'firebase').`.

I tried importing firebase using `import firebase from 'firebase/app`, but still the same error.
I tried commenting StyledFirebaseAuth import and tag and it is working, so I am sure the problem is with react-firebaseui.
This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.4.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "^24.9.1",
    "@types/node": "^12.19.2",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.54",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.9",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.9",
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "firebase": "^8.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-firebaseui": "^4.1.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.0",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.6",
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.13.1",
    "customize-cra": "^1.0.0",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.1.6"
  }
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Please edit the question to show your package.json.  The versions of each library matter. If you changed something recently, say what that is.

Comment: I think you need to import `firebase` before `react-firebase`. Can you check that?

Comment: @ShubhamVerma I tried importing firebase before react-firebaseui, but I still got the error, the import is like that in the documentation too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you've upgraded your "firebase" dependency to 8.0.0 but the "firebaseui" dependency doesn't support it yet.  You will have to temporarily downgrade firebase to version 7.24.0 until firebaseui and react-firebaseui support the [breaking changes in 8.0.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#version_800_-_october_26_2020).

Comment: is there no other walk around

Answer (score 2):

import firebase has changed with the version of 9.0.0, now there is compatibility available no need to downgrade, so you can use /compat folder in your imports,

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'
```